# Java : BST - removing a node with no children doesn't work

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, nodes

I am using a linked node to represent BST.
I can find a node without children, but the remove method for this node doesn't work:

After I add a single node with the value "cat", so my BST has only one node without children.

I tried to remove the "cat" node, only to find out that the remove method does not work - the "cat" node is still in the BST.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?Thanks

```
public class BinarySearchTree {

Node root;

public BinarySearchTree() {
    root = null;
}

/*
 * Adds the specified node to the BST
 */
public String add(String value) {
    if (root == null) {
        root = new Node(value);
        return value;
    }
    return add(root, value);
}

public String add(Node root, String value) {
    int comparision = value.compareTo(root.data);

    if (comparision < 0) {
        if (root.left != null)
            return add(root.left, value);
        root.left = new Node(value);
        return value;
    }

    if (comparision > 0) {
        if (root.right != null)
            return add(root.right, value);
        root.right = new Node(value);
        return value;
    }
    return value;// not allow duplicate
}

/*
 * Returns true if the string is found in the BST
 */
public boolean contains(String value) {
    return contains(root, value);
}

private boolean contains(Node root, String value) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }

    int comparison = value.compareTo(root.data);
    if (comparison == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    if (comparison < 0) {
        return contains(root.left, value);
    } else {
        return contains(root.right, value);
    }
}

/*
 * Checks whether the tree is empty or not
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

/*
 * Removes the specified string from the BST
 */
public boolean remove(String s) {
    if (contains(s) == false) {
        return false;
    }
    return remove(root, s);
}

public boolean remove(Node root, String s) {
    if (root == null) {
        return false;
    }

    int comparision = s.compareTo(root.data);

    if (comparision == 0) {
        if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");
            root = null;
            return true;
        } else if (root.left != null && root.right != null) {
            Node temp = root;
            String min = minValue(temp.right).data;
            root.data = min;
            removemin(root.right);
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (comparision < 0) {
        if (root.left.data.equals(s)) {
            if (root.left.left == null || root.left.right == null) {
                root.left = root.left.right;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return remove(root.left, s);
    }

    if (comparision > 0) {
        if (root.right.data.equals(s)) {
            if (root.right.right == null || root.right.left == null) {
                root.right = root.right.left;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return remove(root.right, s);
    }
    return false;
}

public Node minValue(Node root) {
    if (root.left == null) {
        return root;
    } else
        return minValue(root.left);
}

public static void removemin(Node root) {
    if (root.left == null) {
        root = null;
    } else
        removemin(root.left);
}

/**
 * Prints the inorder traversal of this tree
 */
public void inorderTraversal() {
    inorderTraversal(root);
}

private void inorderTraversal(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return;
    inorderTraversal(root.left);
    System.out.print(root.data + " ");
    inorderTraversal(root.right);
}

private class Node {
    String data;
    Node left;
    Node right;

    public Node(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

/*
 * Returns the height of the tree
 */
public int getHeight() {
    return getHeight(root);
}

private int getHeight(Node root) {
    if (root == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + Math.max(getHeight(root.left), getHeight(root.right));

}
```

Comment: Does java have a BST type? Does it work for strings? (I wasn't able to find the oracle docs on BinarySearchTree after googling)

Comment: Can't find it in Java 8. Could you post where you found BST code, (i.e. imported/self-wrote) and if your own work, post your BST class?

Comment: use linked node, parent node can have left and right node, I write BST by my self

Comment: In your remove method you're calling `contains(s)`..but where is it?

Comment: @ShanuGupta at the top of his code

Comment: I could see contains take 2 arguements not 1.

Comment: @Shanu Gupta, there twp contains method, first is helper method, after remove(cat) it return true for contains(cat)

Comment: @tiezhuetc i can see only one, where's the 2nd contains method that has one arguement?

Comment: @Shanu Gupta, there are some format issue and I cannot fix it, the first contains(s) is public boolean contains(String value) {
  return contains(root, value);
 }

Comment: got it now, but you haven't posted code for `inorderTraversal` and `add` methods.

Comment: @Shanu Gupta, it is complete now

Comment: You don't need two classes. Every node is a BST.

Comment: @EJP,I only need to write remove method, other part is fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem is with the remove method** in this part:

```
if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
    System.out.println("----------------------------------");
    root = null;
    return true;
}
```

You're expecting the remove the root, but its not removing because **`java is pass by value.`** So when you're doing `root = null;` you are setting the copied variable to `null` and not the BST's `root.`

Here's your updated `remove` method. I've renamed `root` to `node` for less confusion.

```
public boolean remove(Node node, String s) {
    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }

    int comparision = s.compareTo(node.data);

    if (comparision == 0) {
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            System.out.println("----------------------------------");
            if (node.equals(root))
                this.root = null;
            node = null;
            return true;
        } else if (node.left != null && node.right != null) {
            Node temp = node;
            String min = minValue(temp.right).data;
            node.data = min;
            removemin(node.right);
            return true;
        }
    }

    if (comparision < 0) {
        if (node.left.data.equals(s)) {
            if (node.left.left == null || node.left.right == null) {
                node.left = node.left.right;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return remove(node.left, s);
    }

    if (comparision > 0) {
        if (node.right.data.equals(s)) {
            if (node.right.right == null || node.right.left == null) {
                node.right = node.right.left;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return remove(node.right, s);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Notice this part of code, where I'm setting `this.root` to `null`.

```
if (node.equals(root))
    this.root = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your `remove(Node root, String s)` method, after identifying that `root` contains the value of `s`, you only change the variable `root` to reference null. This doesn't affect the parent of root's left or right child because it never references them.

A typical BST delete method will return a node such that you can do something like:

```
//...
if(valueToDelete.compareTo(root.value) == 0){
  if(root.left == null && root.right == null){
    return null;
  }
  // Otherwise some juggling of children into a new shape
  // ... actual code here
  return someNodeThatWasDescendantOfRoot
}else if(valueToDelete.compareTo(root.value) < 0){
  root.left = delete(root.left, valueToDelete)
  return root;
}else{
  root.right = delete(root.right, valueToDelete)
  return root;
}
//...
```

The assignment to the child node that may be affected allows for the result of the deletion to then update its parent if necessary, without requiring children to reference their parents.